# Wordpress - get 5 popular posts by views without plugin

Tags: wordpress

Hi,

I have custom fields with image from posts, and I want to display the top 5 posts sorting by views. I am using WordPress, can you help me please?

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  And you're also asking for someone to write code for you, which is not likely going to happen.  What are your custom fields? Are you tracking views of the post? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's one error with [Xhynk's reference](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/):

The query it runs returns posts in alphabetical order (1, 2, 20, 23, 3, 4, etc)

You just need to change

```
'orderby' => 'wpb_post_views_count'
```

to

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
```

For the top 5, use:

```
$popularpost  = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC'
));
```

Answer (score 6):

It is very easy. Just use this code into your functions.php

```
/*
 * Set post views count using post meta
 */
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $countKey = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $countKey, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $countKey);
        add_post_meta($postID, $countKey, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $countKey, $count);
    }
}
```

put single.php

```
setPostViews(get_the_ID());
```

This is your popular post query:

```
   <?php
      query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&posts_per_page=5&orderby=meta_value_num&
      order=DESC');
      if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();
     ?></a>
   </li>
   <?php
   endwhile; endif;
   wp_reset_query();
   ?>
```

For details [go](http://www.codexworld.com/wordpress-how-to-display-most-popular-posts-by-views/)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/

Basically it's adding a meta field to each post - and deletes the old record when it's viewed, then replaces it with 'old record + 1'

Answer (score 0):

[Kabir Hossain's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40338712/8646418) can be shortened:

Since `get_post_meta()` returns `false` if no meta has been found, we can simply use this code to record views:

```
/*
 * Set post views count using post meta
 */
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $countKey = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $countKey, true);
    update_post_meta($postID, $countKey, ((int)$count)+1);
}
```

`((int)$count)` means that if `$count` is `false` it will become 0;

Then, there's no real need to delete post meta as there's no way to decrease the number of views with our code. The function will run on the first post load and create the meta. If the meta has been created before this function has been run, then, well, we've had stats on this post that we can update.

Also, there's no need for `add_post_meta` (especially adding 0 on the first view), as the `update_post_meta()` will create meta if it does not exist.

I also added a check to exclude admins from view stats and to allow this to run exlusively on posts, and hooked the function to template redirect:

```
 //place your theme's functions.php
 /*
 * Set post views count using post meta
 */
 function setPostViews($postID=null) {
     if(!is_single() || 'post' !== get_post_type() || current_user_can('administrator')) return;
     $postID = !empty($postID) ? $postID : get_the_ID();
     $countKey = 'post_views_count';
     $count = get_post_meta($postID, $countKey, true);
     update_post_meta($postID, $countKey, ((int)$count)+1);
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'setPostViews');
```