# get 5 id and title of popular posts in the wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm an android developer. I included `require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');` in a separated file as a web service.

now,I would like to get 5 titles and ids of popular posts.

I found below link, but I do not have enough acknowledge about it.

[Wordpress - get 5 popular posts by views without plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570746/wordpress-get-5-popular-posts-by-views-without-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a custom page template, and put everything there what is needed, in this case, the title.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

You can get the title here
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

It is not a good idea I think to separate the logic like this, it is a better way, if you are using the core functionality, and create the custom template as your need

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code .

```
require('../../../wp-load.php');  // correct this with file location
$popularpost  = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5) );  // will contain all data
$data=array();
foreach($popularpost as $key=>$post)
{
  $data[]['id']=$post->ID;
   $data[]['id']=$post->title;
}
echo json_encode($data) ; // just to return json data for android
```

Comment: I would like to get 5 popular posts !

Comment: then you need to count the posts on per click follow this http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/